# ¿Puede un método con decorador ser de tipo staticmethod?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decoradores

Para gestionar unas consultas de datos estoy creando una clase genérica del tipo:

```
class MisDatos(object):
    _instance = None

    @staticmethod
    def get_instance(func):
        if MisDatos._instance is None:
            MisDatos._instance = conexion()

        return MisDatos._instance

    @staticmethod
    def anyade_valores(var):
        mi_instancia = MisDatos.get_instance()

        return mi_instancia.get(var)

    @staticmethod
    def elimina_valores(var):
        mi_instancia = MisDatos.get_instance()

        return mi_instancia.delete(var)
```

Se observa la estructura con un singleton, para estar siempre utilizando la misma conexión.

Dado que cada método llama siempre en primer lugar a `get_instance()` (es decir, la línea `mi_instancia = MisDatos.get_instance()`), pensé que lo mejor sería hacer un decorator para automatizar esta parte:

```
class MisDatos(object):
    _instance = None

    @staticmethod
    def get_instance(func):
        def check_instance():
            if MisDatos._instance is None:
                MisDatos._instance = conexion()
            return func()
        return check_instance

    @staticmethod
    @get_instance
    def anyade_valores(var):

        return MisDatos._instance.get(var)
```

Sin embargo, actualmente me está diciendo:

> ```
> TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
> ```

¿Cómo podría corregir esta estructura? ¿Es esta una manera *correcta* de realizar lo que quiero o, por contra, estoy complicándome más de la cuenta?

Comment: El problema realmente no es que un método decorado no pueda ser estático, el problema está en que el decorador en sí (`get_instance`) es declarado como estático.  `staticmethod` retorna  un [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) y no una función, lo que causa que al decorar con `@get_instance` falle al no ser "callable". Hay varias opciones si quieres usar un decorador, entre ellas declararlo fuera de la clase,  crear una clase que agrupe estos métodos auxiliares, etc Por cierto `check_instance()` necesita recibir el parámetro `var`.

Comment: @FJSevilla ah, ahora entiendo por qué falla. El tema es que `get_instance()` debería estar dentro de la clase, pues si no no puedo accedir a `MisDatos._instance` desde fuera. Deberé explorar la clase que agrupe los auxiliares, aunque parece que se complicaría demasiado.

Comment: Si no se me está escapando algo, `MisDatos._instance` al ser un atributo de clase y no de instancia es accesible desde fuera de la clase siempre que puedas hacer referencia a `MisDatos`, por ejemplo si sacas el decorador de la clase pero lo dejas en el mismo módulo no debe haber ningún problema. Si no usas  `@staticmethod` con el decorador  también funcionaría tal y como lo tienes ahora.  Incluso se puede hacer que el propio decorador acepte `MisDatos` como argumento. En cualquier caso no olvides hacer que el wrapper reciba `var` para que puede  retornar `func(var)` como comentaba antes.

Answer (score 0):

Sí es posible.
Te adjunto detalle en el código

```
"""
@staticmethod utilidad y uso

Para qué sirve @staticmethod
1. Para incorporar métodos a una Clase con comportamiento limitado
2. No tiene acceso a los atributos de Objeto
3. Se pueden invocar desde la Clase sin necesidad de instanciar un objeto
4. Sería equivalente a una función fuera de la Clase
5. El diseñador la incluye dentro de la Clase por razones de diseño
6. Se señaliza, anteponiendo el decorador @staticmethod
7. @staticmethod impide que en su definición se incluya (self) para evitar que tenga acceso al namespace del objeto

Como se comenta en las siguientes aserciones, sobre todo las Nº 9 y 10:
"""

class A:
    aa=11                                         # 1.Atributo de Clase y Objeto. Forma parte de namespace de la Clase.
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.b=22                                 # 2. Atributo de Objeto. Forma parte del namespace del Objeto en cuanto se instancie
        #self.e=aa+1                              # 3. ERROR. aa no está definida. No se permite leer ni modificar el namespace de la Clase
    def hello(self):
        self.b=self.b+1                           # 4. Se permite leer y modificar las variables del namespace del Objeto
        print ("Nuevo valor de b= ", self.b)                
        f=66                                      # 5. Variable f, existe sólo en el tiempo de vida de la ejecución de hello() 
        print(f)                                 

# Operaciones desde la Clase
A.c=33                                            # 6. Añade al manespace de la Clase una nueva variable, a partir de aquí los Objetos instanciados incorporan este nuevo atributo
A.aa =55                                          # 7. Cambia de valor en el namespace de la Clase el atributo aa, a partir de aquí los Objetos instanciados se actualizan al nuevo valor
#A.hello()                                        # 8.  ERROR. 

#Opraciones desde el Objeto
oa=A("KK")
oa.hello()



print(" ***** Ahora con @staticmethod ***********")



class B:
    aa=11                         
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.b=22                 
        #self.e=aa+1              
    @staticmethod
    def hello():                                  # 9. Con @staticmethod NO se permite poner hello(self), y así no da acceso al namespace con las variables de Objeto. Está aislado
        print ("Aislado por @staticmethod")                
        f=66                                 

# Operaciones desde la Clase
B.hello()                                         # 10. Con @staticmethod SÍ se permite invocar un método desde la Clase sin instanciar un objeto

#Operaciones desde el Objeto
ob=B("KK")
ob.hello()


print("FIN, usado para poner una parada y ver los namespace")
```